# Suffix tree implementation for large texts

Tags: java, algorithm

I am looking for an implementation of the suffix tree data structure written in Java. Although many implementations are available online, I was unable to find one which can build a suffix tree for relatively large text (e.g., >50MB) without using an excessive amount of memory (e.g., less 3GB for a 50MB input text).

Some research papers (e.g., "Reducing the Space Requirement of Suffix Trees" by Kurtz) claims that it is possible to implement a suffix tree with a space overhead of 10-40 bytes per input character depending on the specific technique. However, most Java implementations seem to require much more memory.

Can you suggest a *space-efficient* implementation of suffix tree written in Java?

Comment: Just to clarify: Prefix, Suffix or Infix?

Comment: @Traubenfuchs OP is talking about suffix tree data structure.

Comment: I can see that. People often confuse them though (;

Comment: And I was about to give an answer. What a shame.

Comment: Hi, yes I was referring to suffix trees. I don't know how to actually improve my question without spending many hours trying to implement some techniques explained inside some papers. (I can list all the Java implementations which are not space-efficient but I don't think this will improve my question). This was an attempt to understand if some java libraries for space-efficient suffix tree are already available on the web.